# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials:(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: android, java-native-interface, webrtc, videochat, peer-connection

I am working on one module having functionality of Video Chat. for this i am using Webrtc. i am very close to done this but i am getting one issue while calling.

Server always returns

```
{"params": {"messages": []}, "result": "FULL"}
```

and after this i am getting one other issue like,

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

First i had issue for jingle native library. i have integrated it in jni directory too. also updated peerconnection_jni.cc file but same error..

i can attach peerconnection_jni.cc file too ( if require ).

i have searched on google too. but not getting actual output. can anyone please help me?

UPDATE :

This is the code of my peerconnection_jni.cc

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldTrials
    (JNIEnv* evn,jclass _class,jstring j_trials_init_string) {
        field_trials_init_string = NULL;
        if (j_trials_init_string != NULL) {
            const char* init_string =
                    jni->GetStringUTFChars(j_trials_init_string, NULL);
            int init_string_length = jni->GetStringUTFLength(j_trials_init_string);
            field_trials_init_string = new char[init_string_length + 1];
            rtc::strcpyn(field_trials_init_string, init_string_length + 1, init_string);
            jni->ReleaseStringUTFChars(j_trials_init_string, init_string);
            LOG(LS_INFO) << "initializeFieldTrials: " << field_trials_init_string;
        }
        webrtc::field_trial::InitFieldTrialsFromString(field_trials_init_string);
    }
}
```

This is my Logcat output.

```
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645): Fatal error: Native method not found: org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials(Native Method)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at org.appspot.apprtc.PeerConnectionClient.createPeerConnectionFactoryInternal(PeerConnectionClient.java:268)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at org.appspot.apprtc.PeerConnectionClient.access$18(PeerConnectionClient.java:257)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at org.appspot.apprtc.PeerConnectionClient$1.run(PeerConnectionClient.java:222)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 19:20:57.041: E/AppRTCDemoActivity(26645):    at org.appspot.apprtc.util.LooperExecutor.run(LooperExecutor.java:57)
```

Comment: From where your calling initializeFieldTrials() method?? and are you loading native library before calling that method??

Comment: i am calling initializeFieldTrials method from PeerConnectionClient.java > createPeerConnectionFactoryInternal() method. and yes i am loading that library using "static { System.loadLibrary("jingle_peerconnection_so");}" at the top of this class.

Comment: okay..if your using JNI method,then that method name should contains some naming conventions. Have you used that naming convention? and which field your passing through that method? i think string ..right?

Comment: Yes its string. check i have updated my question and attached peerconnection_jni.cc code for that method.

Comment: Your method naming convention should be, JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldIdTrials(JNIEnv* evn,jclass _class,jstring j_trials_init_string), And your java method should be static. if that method is not static in java use jobject instead of jclass in jni method.

Comment: let me check with JNI naming convention. and yes my java method is static.

Comment: ok try out that naming convention and let me know..

Comment: @Sarita : Please check updated jni code in question. is it ok? i have i have bit less knowledge about jni.cc files so..

Comment: Seems like an appropriate DLL or SO file is not available.

Comment: i have libjingle_peerconnection_so.so files available in both armeabi and armeabi-v7a directory inside libs.

Comment: yah your jni method is fine..can u post your java method? and Android.mk file. So that i can comes to know where you did mistake. And try to use "const char*" instead of "jstring". Sometimes this may give problem i m not very sure.

Comment: @Sarita : Can you please give me your mail id? i can send you demo i have downloaded from google webrtc svn.

Comment: ok thanx and Sarita i have downloaded this demo from google webrtc svn and merged that demo and libraries.

Comment: Since your source file's extension indicates it to be a C++ program, have you enclosed the method or its prototype in extern "C" {} to avoid **name mangling**?  If not, it will fail in precisely the way you have found.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to initialize an object.
So, i guess your method is NOT static.
You need the second parameter to be the object that invokes the method, not the object's class:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldTrials
    (JNIEnv* evn,    jobject _thiz     ,jstring j_trials_init_string)
```